# Is there anyway you could stop a data driven subscription in SSRS 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-agent-job

Is there anyway you can stop a DDS?  I have a process that adds a .pdf in 400 different folders.  I was just wondering if there way anyway to stop it because sometimes it interferes with other things on the server I'm working on it and it slows it down significantly.

Answer (score 2):

There's no supported way to do this.  There is a hack you can try, but it involves manipulating the tables in the ReportServer database, which is unpredictable at best.  Here are the steps:

1. Stop the SSRS server.  This will make it quit sending new subscriptions, but it doesn't actually stop the DDS.
2. Find the relevant row in the ActiveSubscriptions table.
3. Delete all of the rows in the Notifications table with an ActivationID that corresponds to the ActiveID in ActiveSubscriptions.
4. Delete the row in ActiveSubscriptions.
5. Restart the SSRS server

Any subscriptions that SSRS had already queued up with the SQL Server Agent will still be processed, but it should stop sending new ones.  As I said, this is a hack, and it's difficult to say what else you might break by doing this.